# Is there a way to update an attribute field with a hotkey?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, editing

I am examining several thousands of polygon features and use a grid to focus on every part of the area of interest. I use the Go2NextFeature Tool to jump to the grid cell when all polygon features are ok. If so, I update an attribute field "Status" with 1 to change the styling, so that I know which parts are finished.

However, I try to save time while editing, so I am wondering if there is a way to update the Status field with 1 using a hotkey? Maybe it is possible by an expression in the attribute form section of the layer properties?

Another possibility would be to modify the Go2NextFeature Tool, so that it automatically updates when I click on the next feature button (F8). I guess it would not be much code, but I am not experienced in Plugin development.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this python script I have modified for your purpose

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction

class Toggler():
    FIELD_NAME = "Status"  # Change this variable to change the field to modify
    SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY = True  # Change this to False for the action to apply to all features in layer
    VALUE_TO_APPLY = 1  # Change this variable to change the applied value upon activation of key
    KEY_SET_LAYER = "Alt+K"
    KEY_PERFORM_ACTION = "K"

    def __init__(self):
        super(Toggler, self).__init__()
        self.root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
        self.current = None

        # Setup keybinding to set the current layer upon which the following actions will be performed
        self.set_toggle_action = QAction("Set Current Layer", iface.mainWindow())
        iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.set_toggle_action, self.KEY_SET_LAYER)
        iface.addPluginToMenu("&Set Current Layer", self.set_toggle_action)
        self.set_toggle_action.triggered.connect(self.setCurrentLayer)

        # Setup keybinding for changing the feature attribute
        self.toggle_action = QAction("Change Status For Layer",  iface.mainWindow())
        iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.toggle_action, self.KEY_PERFORM_ACTION)
        iface.addPluginToMenu("&Change Status For Layer", self.toggle_action)
        self.toggle_action.triggered.connect(self.changeStatus)

    def setCurrentLayer(self):
        current_layer = iface.activeLayer()
        if current_layer:
            self.current = self.root.findLayer(current_layer.id())
        else:
            iface.messageBar().pushWarning("Shortcut Warning", "No layer in legend to setup shortcut".format(self.KEY_SET_LAYER))
            
    def changeStatus(self):
        if not self.current:
            iface.messageBar().pushWarning("Shortcut Warning", "No layer set for shortcut (use {})".format(self.KEY_SET_LAYER))
            return
        index_field = self.current.layer().fields().indexFromName(self.FIELD_NAME)

        if self.SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY:
            # For selected features
            feat_ids = (feature.id() for feature in self.current.layer().selectedFeatures())
        else:
            # For all the features
            feat_ids = self.current.layer().allFeatureIds()

        # Update FIELD_NAME field to 1 for features corresponding to feat_ids
        dict_values_to_change = {idfeat: {index_field: self.VALUE_TO_APPLY} for idfeat in feat_ids}
        self.current.layer().dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(dict_values_to_change)

toggle = Toggler()
```

However this solution requires you to reload this script everytime you launch qgis.
For it to be persistent you would either have to use a plugin or you could indeed modify the Go2NextFeature Tool to execute the code in `changeStatus` along with whatever else that tool does upon pressing F8

Comment: Do I have to change things under "" at line 19, 21, 25 and 27?

Comment: You dont 'have' to but you can, they are just names which can be seen in the Plugin menu. They allow you to use the fonctionality via the menus or/and see the keybinding

Comment: do I have to load it via pluginbuilder, or simply via python console?

Comment: As i said you can run it via the python console when you need it (every time you restart qgis, you have to run it again). Or you can integrate it inside a plugin to make the loading of the keybinding automatic

Comment: when I run it in the script editor it tells me "Seems there is no valid script in the file". When I run it in the console I get this `exec(open('C:/Users/Patrick/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/scripts/update_Satus.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())`

Comment: when you run it in the console what it output is correct, to make sure it worked you can see in the Plugin menu in the toolbar you should see "Set Current Layer" and "Change Status For Layer" in the dropdown menu. I edited my response to add little helpful warning when using the shortcuts. btw to use it, you run it the console then "Alt+k" to make the selected layer in the legend actif then "k" to change the attribute in the active layer for selected features

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. When I run it in the console I get error messages about wrong indentation. And if I load it via the script editor, what seems comfortable to me, it tells me that the script is not valid (see above).